# What TV series had an adaptation of "Inconstant Moon"?

Tags: tv, episode-identification, larry-niven

Larry Niven wrote a short story called "Inconstant Moon." It starts with the hero waking up in the middle of the night to find that the moon is drastically brighter than he has ever seen it. Wackiness ensues.

I seem to recall that this was made into an episode of one of those episodic series like *The Twilight Zone* or *The Outer Limits*. But I can't seem to find it. Does anybody know if it was, and which series? And maybe a year or a season or something? I'd like to buy the DVD if I can find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The Outer Limits* [season 2, episode 12](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667911/) (h/t [Alith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/74137/alith)), aired April 12, 1996.

A Season 2 DVD is available in the usual online sales outlets.

Comment: And the best ever episode of the Outer Limits it was. :)